# Angular | How to add parameter to URL (some-url?param1=foo)

Tags: angular

Normally adding parameters to the route in Angular is quite easy:

```
route.navigate(['some-url', param]);
```

**Question:** How can I add an "old school" parameter to a angular route? Ex (not working):

```
let param = 'foo'    
route.navigate(['some-url', param, '?someparam=true']);
```

Expected results:

```
some-url/foo?someparam=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you have to do:

```
this.router.navigate(['/some-url/foo'], { queryParams: { someparam: true } });
```

Here you have more information:

- https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments
- https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/